# Verifying Injectivity of Some Module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

So I have the folowing ring $R= \left\lbrace \left(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b&c\\0&d&e\\0&0&f\end{smallmatrix}\right) : \mbox{all entries are in some field }  \mathbb{K} \right\rbrace $.

I consider the $R$-module $M$ = the space of all $3 \times 1$ matrices with entries  in $\mathbb{K}$.

I want to prove that

(1) $M$ is an  injective $R$-module

(2) For any submodule $N$ of $M$, $M/N$ is injective.

I know we have four equivalent statements to prove injectivity of an $R$-module and the Baer criterion of course; none of which worked for me.

Can someone please give me a hint as to how I can start with the proofs?

Comment: Hint: The ring is hereditary. So it is enough to show that $M$ is injective.

Comment: @user Not at all... I am still trying to figure this MSE thing out; i.e. how it works.

Comment: @RobertM Could you maybe give me a hint how to prove that it's injective?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you are familiar with the concept of injective hulls.

Use the fact that the injective hull of $_RR$ is $M_3(\mathbb{K})$, the set of all $3\times 3$ matrices. This means that $M_3(\mathbb{K})$ is a an injective left $R$-module. Therefore any direct summand of $M_3(\mathbb{K})$ is also an injective $R$-module. Note that $M$ is clearly a direct summand of $M_3(\mathbb{K})$ (as an $R$-module) and thus $M$ is injective. This proves (1). On the other hand the ring $R$ is both left and right hereditary therefore any quotient of an injective $R$-module is also injective which together with (1) proves (2).

Comment: Thanks! I just read about injective hulls, but how is it clear that injective hull of $R$ as a left $R$-module is in fact $M_3(\mathbb{K})$?

Comment: @Mia Welcome. This is not that clear! But it is well known. For example see Example 3.43 in Lam's great book: Lectures on modules and rings.